# The images defined on the src from <img> are not showing on my heroku app

Tags: node.js, image, heroku

The problem that I have is the following:

[An image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1lQs.png)

As you can see, the alt works and only that works.

The code for the < img>:

```
<img src="imagens/peninsula.png" class="ideia-imagens" alt="choose places">
```

I've searched for different solutions, but most of them were just to change the relative path. I tried to do that, but none of them worked.

I'm using Node.JS and ExpressJS on my Heroku app. I have a public folder. The images are in public/imagens.

**EDIT:** I have three images like this, got two of them working just by letting them written like the code up there, but this one isn't working yet.

Comment: Hi, where are stored your picture files? Do you have a `public/` folder into your app folder? Could you please provide more information about your setup: Are you using ExpressJS, ...?

Comment: @rphonika I've edited the question

Comment: Please look at the ExpressJS documentation for serving static files: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html. Do you have the following line: `app.use(express.static('public'))` in your app config?

Comment: I do. Which is weird

Comment: Are you able to see the picture when you hit the following URL: `http://localhost:[YOUR_PORT]/imagens/peninsula.png`. Did you tried with `src="/imagens/peninsula.png"`.